# netplan vs NetworkManager on Ubuntu 18.04 and above

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan

What is the concept of `renderer` in a `netplan` configuration file?

What practical difference does it make between choosing a `networkd` and a `NetworkNamager` renderer?

Can anyone (in the second case) proceed with `nmtui` or `nmcli`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The difference the `renderer` makes, is the decision to run either `systemd-networkd` or `NetworkManager`. This distinction is identified by a file in `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

`networkd` is normally used in server installations, where the network environment is fairly static.

`NetworkManager` is normally used in desktop installations, and was used in all prior versions of Ubuntu. `NetworkManager` is easier to use in environments where network requirements change a lot... like in wireless networking. nmcli/nmtui/etc are `NetworkManager` commands.

To use `NetworkManager`, your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file should look like:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: so if I opt for `renderer: NetworkManager`, then I can run `nmcli` / `nmtui` to configure my network? what if I run nm and provide configurations that are conflicting with the ones in the `netplan` `.yml` file? which one (the config entered via nm or the `yaml` settings) prevails?

Comment: @pkaramol once you specify `renderer: NetworkManager` you're done with all .yaml files, and all normal NetworkManager commands can be used. All conflict or error scripts will need to be rectified via NM.