# No ethernet link detected on Ubuntu 18.04 for unknown reason

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, network-manager, ethernet

I am running into an issue on my Dell device where during boot up, the ethernet link light is on but then it goes off after fully booting and the two ethernet ports are no longer recognized.

This is my system information:

- Dell 3002 Gateway
- Linux-X64-Generic
- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Kernel: 4.15.0-1045-oem

I know that the ethernet cables and ports are working just fine. After a fresh install of Ubuntu, the ports and cables work like normal. The issue is, I have a few of these, and randomly 30% of them, the ports fail.

**First attempt:**
I have been using Netplan to manage my physical ports via networked and NetworkManager for my sim card. I figured that using two managers might be causing issues so I changed Netplan to render my physical ports in Network Manager according to this post: [netplan vs NetworkManager on Ubuntu 18.04 and above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122757/netplan-vs-networkmanager-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-above)

I thought this worked because the IP addresses I assigned to the ports showed up with ``` ifconfig`` and ``` nmcli c``` shows the ports as active. However, I was still unable to ping anything on the local network.

**Second attempt:**
I found a very similar post to my issue that suggested downgrading the ethernet controller from r8169 to r8168: [Ethernet not working well in Ubuntu 18.04 on new desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043384/ethernet-not-working-well-in-ubuntu-18-04-on-new-desktop)

I could not get r8168 to replace r8169 and figured it was because of the kernel. I figured that r8101 was the version that I needed for my kernel and downloaded/installed it with success. Now when viewing my driver info, I see that r8101 is being used instead of r8169. This sadly did not work.

Additionally, when I reboot the machine, the ports in Network Manager shows as "down" and I have to re-enable them with `nmcli c up netplan-eth1` every time. This still does not let me ping anything on the local network.

**This is the relevant information from my machine:**

`lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

> 02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
> Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:07b9]
> Kernel driver in use: r8101
> Kernel modules: r8169, r8101

> 04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
> Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:07b9]
> Kernel driver in use: r8101
> Kernel modules: r8169, r8101

`lshw -C network`

> *-network UNCLAIMED
> description: Ethernet controller
> product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
> vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
> version: 07
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
> configuration: latency=0
> resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:80304000-80304fff memory:80300000-80303fff

> *-network UNCLAIMED
> description: Ethernet controller
> product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
> vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
> version: 07
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
> configuration: latency=0
> resources: ioport:c000(size=256) memory:80204000-80204fff memory:80200000-80203fff

`nmcli c`

> SIM                 xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx  gsm       cdc-wdm0 (green)

> netplan-eth0        xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx  ethernet  eth0 (green)

> netplan-eth1        xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx  ethernet  eth1 (green)

> Ifupdown (eth1)     xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx  ethernet  --

> Wired connection 1  xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx  ethernet  --

> Wired connection 2  xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx  ethernet  --

Very lost as what this issue could be. I feel like I have tried everything at this point. Curious if there is something I may have missed or have misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel 4.15 is ancient, so best re-test with an up-to-date kernel. If the issue persists, a full dmesg log would be needed.