# Without Network Manager - why does dhclient work, but configuration in /etc/network/interface does not?

Tags: network-manager, dhcp

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 with Network Manager disabled because it doesn't support some of the features required by Wi-Fi 6E.
I'm performing the manual configuration based on [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic).

When starting the system, the network interfaces do not obtain an IPv4 address with DHCP.
The system has two interface, enp0s31f6 and wlp2s0, which are Ethernet and Wi-Fi respectively.

/etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
```

With this file, neither interface obtains an IPv4 address with DHCP.

However if I issue these terminal commands

```
sudo dhclient enp0s31f6
sudo dhclient wlp2s0
```

the interfaces will obtain addresses from DHCP and operate normally (until the next restart)

Why is the /etc/network/interfaces file not causing this to happen when the system starts?

Comment: The linked article looks rather old - it doesn't even mention `netplan` for example. When you disabled NetworkManager, did you configure `netplan` to use an alternate renderer? See for example [netplan vs NetworkManager on Ubuntu 18.04 and above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122757/netplan-vs-networkmanager-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-above)

Answer (score 0):

I think is the same reason as debian.
NetworkManager does not manage any interface defined in /etc/network/interfaces by default.

Unmanaged devices means NetworkManager doesn't handle those network devices.

https://wiki.debian.org//NetworkManager#Wired_Networks_are_Unmanaged

leave just lo interface in that file:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```